# convert kdb to kdbx files on linux mint

Tags: linux-mint, keepass

I'm trying to import a kdb to kdbx file on keepass.
Unfortunately it says, that this import of kdb data is only supported on windows.
Any idea how I can solve this ?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install KeePassX from the software center, which can open KDB file. You can then export the passwords to another format like XML, then import it from KeePass.

Note that when importing XML from KeePass, select format "KeePassX XML", rather than "KeePass XML (1.x)".

Answer (score -1):

you can export you database to cvs file. You must create new db for your app. and finally you can import cvs file comfortable

Comment: How does one do what you describe?  If the author knew how they likely wouldn't have this answer.